# Python TypeHint Optional dataclass as None inside dataclass results in mypy error

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-dataclasses

I am having a hard time to wrap my head around type hints for dataclasses.
I have a dataclass Sudoku that creates another dataclass Grid with the method create_grid.
The Grid class needs the size variable of the Sudoku in order to initialize correctly.
Therefore i typehint the Grid dataclass as Grid | None and set it to None as i cannot use the default_factory of the field method if I have attributes to pass.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from grid import Grid

@dataclass
class Sudoku:
    size: int
    grid: Grid | None = None

    def create_grid(self) -> None:
        """Create the grid"""
        self.grid = Grid(size=self.size)

    def load_grid_values_from_string(self, grid_string: str) -> None:
        """Load sudoku from a string"""
        self.create_grid()
        self.grid.load_grid_values(grid_string)
```

However mypy does not like this. My Grid dataclass has the method load_grid_values implemented, and the code runs fine, but mypy still gives this this error message:

```
Item "None" of "Optional[Grid]" has no attribute "load_grid_values"  [union-attr]mypy
```

How do I type hint this correctly? I used `__post_init__` before and passed the self.size but this gives the same error message.

Comment: The simplest solution would just be a type guard like `if self.grid is not None: self.grid.load_grid_values(grid_string)`. Another option is to have an optional protected `_grid` and a (getter) property `grid` that does that check and raises an error, if `_grid` is `None` and returns it otherwise. Then that could be typed as returning `Grid` and you'd be fine. I am sure I had an answer for this somewhere, but I can't find it right now...

Comment: I'd use `@dataclass(frozen=True)` to make `size` immutable, and then make `grid` a  `functools.cached_property` that's computed based on the `size`.